# Create points with attributes from Cursor

Tags: arcpy, cursor, fields-attributes

I have a table imported from Excel that has three attribute columns (City, State, ZIP) as well as X/Y columns that have been added.

I have a cursor that goes through the records in the table and creates points

```
point = arcpy.Point()
pointGeometryList = []

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("in_memory/xxExcelOutput", ["POINT_X", "POINT_Y", "CITY", "STATE", "ZIP_CODE"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        point.X = row[0]
        point.Y = row[1]

        pointGeometry = arcpy.PointGeometry(point)
        pointGeometryList.append(pointGeometry)

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(pointGeometryList, "in_memory/pointFC")
```

How can I add the attributes from my table when I create the points?  I know the following doesn't work, but is there a way to do it within the same cursor?

```
    for row in cursor:
        point.X = row[0]
        point.Y = row[1] 
        point.ZIP = row[4]
```

The only way I've come up with so far is to AddField() to the new feature class, and then UpdateCursor() the extra attributes with another search cursor.  While this way works OK for my test data (I have some data in my table, for proof of concept), I am concerned that I may end up with multiple points in the same location that have different attributes - I need to ensure that each point is created with the matching attributes.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use arcpy for this instead of the standard "Add X and Y coordinates" function? That would retain all fields. Another arcpy alternative would be to compare X & Y values of the new pts layer to the excel and use an update cursor as you said where they match.

Comment: @GISKid Has to be automated - ArcMap will not be opened.  Your alternative is along the lines of how I'm doing it currently as per my "the only way..." comment at the end of my question.  I'll add a little more information to my question to clarify.

Comment: Since it's point data, you could use [numpy2FC](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/numpyarraytofeatureclass.htm).

Comment: @Paul I'm not familiar with NumPy to FC - the doc you linked to doesn't seem to indicate that *other* fields are possible

Comment: Other fields are possible, see the code sample. [Here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/python/working-with-numpy-in-arcgis.htm) for more info on using numpy.

Comment: Thanks @Paul I figured it out enough to get it working, although I had to use the Numpy docs as I couldn't get it to work based on the Esri docs.  This works more like the way I was expecting than the accepted answer below (which also works), and so I have gone with this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I not sure if this is the answer that you want. but if you are not bound to using an excel sheet, just simply convert your file to csv and read it with the csv module.

```
import csv
import arcpy
import os
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
gdb = r'gdb'
p = r'path\\' #for path
fcname = "nameyouwant"
centers  = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(gdb,fcname,"POINT",'','',"ENABLED",4326)
arcpy.AddField_management(fcname,"City","TEXT")
arcpy.AddField_management(fcname,"State","TEXT")
arcpy.AddField_management(fcname,"Zip","TEXT")
arcpy.AddField_management(fcname,"X","TEXT")
arcpy.AddField_management(fcname,"Y","TEXT")
with open(os.path.join(p,'csvname.csv')) as noury:
    reader = csv.DictReader(noury)
    for row in reader:
        point = arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(row["POINT_X"],row["POINT_Y"]),arcpy.SpatialReference(4326))
        #projected = point.projectAs(arcpy.SpatialReference(SRID)) if you want to project
        with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fcname,("City","State","Zip","X","Y","SHAPE@")) as cur:
            sert = (row['CITY'],row['STATE'],row['ZIP_CODE'],row["POINT_X"],row["POINT_Y"],point) #or use the projected point if you want it projected
            cur.insertRow(sert)
```

Comment: truth is you can probably use the search cursor on the excel table, just modify some of my code

Comment: My table has been pulled from Excel already - the cursors in my question don't touch Excel.  That said, I think I can see what you're doing there with  the insert cursor at the end.  Instead of creating the point first and then creating the feature class of the points, I need to switch it around and create empty feature class (with relevant fields) and then add the points and attributes to it.  I'll give it a go!

Comment: oh gotcha, yeah this should work. Its easier to just insert the rows in the loop so your not trying to store them in a list,variable or dictionary then reloop through that to create the feature class or shapefile

Comment: The last 5 lines of your code sample are what worked for me - `point = arcpy.PointGeometry()` then a Insert Cursor and Search Cursor, inserting the attributes and the `point` at the same time.  Thanks @ziggy

Answer (score 1):

Work around without cursors:

```
table ='C:/Users/Downloads/test.xlsx'
arcpy.ExcelToTable_conversion(table,"table2.dbf")
table2='C:/Users/Documents/ArcGIS/table2.dbf'
arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management("table2","POINT_X","POINT_Y","table2_layer")
```

Comment: Sounds too simple! Unfortunately it is only creating records without geometry... I'll keep playing to see if I can find the cause.  Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Strange, I tested with a dummy excel file with made up integers for POINT_X and Y. Maybe try setting a spatial reference in `MakeXYEventLayer_Management` if the data is projected?

Comment: There may be more wrong with my data, so I'll look further into that.  There is a lot of clean-up that needs to happen on it, so I may have missed something.  I'll let you know if I find it.